# Array dimensions exceeded supported range. .NET API

Tags: .net, loops

Is it possible to loop over an `TimeOnly` type? I'm trying to create an `List<TimeOnly>` using while loop.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Shedule>> CreateNewShedule(SheduleCreateDto sheduleCreateDto)
{
    

    var hours = new List<TimeOnly>{};
    var startHour = TimeOnly.Parse(sheduleCreateDto.StartHour);
    var endHour = TimeOnly.Parse(sheduleCreateDto.EndHour);

    while(!startHour.Equals(endHour)){
        hours.Add(startHour);
        startHour.AddMinutes(15);
    }

    var shedule = new Shedule
    {
        WeekDay = sheduleCreateDto.WeekDay,
        VisitTime = sheduleCreateDto.VisitTime,
        Hours = hours
    };

    _context.Shedules.Add(shedule);
    if( await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0) return Ok(shedule);

    return BadRequest("Failed to add shedule");
}
```

When I post the request it looks like the loop is infinite and then I got the error like this:

> **Array dimensions exceeded supported range.**

It also happens when I use for loop and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that [`TimeOnly.AddMinutes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly.addminutes?view=net-7.0) returns a new `TimeOnly`(since you cannot modify it). So you have to assign it to the variable `startHour`:

```
startHour = startHour.AddMinutes(15);
```

The next issue is that it's possible that the `startHour` never equals the `endHour`. So use `<`:

```
while(startHour < endHour)
{
    hours.Add(startHour);
    startHour = startHour.AddMinutes(15);
}
```

You should also first ensure that you have valid times, so end should come after start:

```
var startHour = TimeOnly.Parse(sheduleCreateDto.StartHour);
var endHour = TimeOnly.Parse(sheduleCreateDto.EndHour);
bool valid = endHour > startHour; // handle invalid now and don't start processing
```

Comment: I added both and the same thing happens. I was thiking that maybe I pass wrong data to create the variables, but when I declare them manually it still doesnt work.

Comment: sharls: You know how to use the debugger? Now would be a good time to use it :)

Comment: Im stil learning it but will try

Comment: @sharls: I found the real issue and edited my answer(first part).

Comment: Yes, it works now. I found out also in debuger that it wasnt incrementing. Thank you.